# Scala: Most concise conversion of a CSS color string to RGB integers

Tags: css, scala, itext, parseint, itext7

I am trying to get the RGB values of a CSS color string and wonder how good my code is:

```
object Color {
  def stringToInts(colorString: String): Option[(Int, Int, Int)] = {
    val trimmedColorString: String = colorString.trim.replaceAll("#", "")
    val longColorString: Option[String] = trimmedColorString.length match {
      // allow only strings with either 3 or 6 letters
      case 3 => Some(trimmedColorString.flatMap(character => s"$character$character"))
      case 6 => Some(trimmedColorString)
      case _ => None
    }
    val values: Option[Seq[Int]] = longColorString.map(_
      .foldLeft(Seq[String]())((accu, character) => accu.lastOption.map(_.toSeq) match {
        case Some(Seq(_, _)) => accu :+ s"$character" // previous value is complete => start with succeeding
        case Some(Seq(c)) => accu.dropRight(1) :+ s"$c$character" // complete the previous value
        case _ => Seq(s"$character") // start with an incomplete first value
      })
      .flatMap(hexString => scala.util.Try(Integer.parseInt(hexString, 16)).toOption)
      // .flatMap(hexString => try {
      //  Some(Integer.parseInt(hexString, 16))
      // } catch {
      //   case _: Exception => None
      // })
    )
    values.flatMap(values => values.size match {
      case 3 => Some((values.head, values(1), values(2)))
      case _ => None
    })
  }
}

// example:

println(Color.stringToInts("#abc")) // prints Some((170,187,204))
```

You may run that example on https://scastie.scala-lang.org

The parts of that code I am most unsure about are

- the `match` in the `foldLeft` (is it a good idea to use string interpolation or can the code be written shorter without string interpolation?)
- <strike>`Integer.parseInt` in conjunction with `try` (can I use a prettier alternative in Scala?)</strike> (solved thanks to excellent comment by Xavier Guihot)

But I expect most parts of my code to be improvable. I do not want to introduce new libraries in addition to `com.itextpdf` to shorten my code, but using `com.itextpdf` functions is an option. (The result of `stringToInts` is going to be converted into a `new com.itextpdf.kernel.colors.DeviceRgb(...)`, thus I have installed `com.itextpdf` anyway.)

Tests defining the expected function:

```
import org.scalatest.{BeforeAndAfterEach, FunSuite}

class ColorTest extends FunSuite with BeforeAndAfterEach {

  test("shorthand mixed case color") {
    val actual: Option[(Int, Int, Int)] = Color.stringToInts("#Fa#F")
    val expected = (255, 170, 255)
    assert(actual === Some(expected))
  }

  test("mixed case color") {
    val actual: Option[(Int, Int, Int)] = Color.stringToInts("#1D9a06")
    val expected = (29, 154, 6)
    assert(actual === Some(expected))
  }

  test("too short long color") {
    val actual: Option[(Int, Int, Int)] = Color.stringToInts("#1D9a6")
    assert(actual === None)
  }

  test("too long shorthand color") {
    val actual: Option[(Int, Int, Int)] = Color.stringToInts("#1D9a")
    assert(actual === None)
  }

  test("invalid color") {
    val actual: Option[(Int, Int, Int)] = Color.stringToInts("#1D9g06")
    assert(actual === None)
  }

}
```

Comment: Concerning the try/catch, you can use `.flatMap(hexString => Try(Integer.parseInt(hexString, 16)).toOption)` instead

Comment: Excellent alternative. Many thanks.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ might be more appropriate for this question

Comment: I thought about that, but on the other hand it is not so much about code architecture than Scala language features.

Comment: You might want to change your test from `actual === Some(expected)` to `actual.contains(expected)` which I personally think is a bit clearer.

Comment: Thank you. Isn't it also a little bit faster using `contains`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment of writing this answer the other answers don't properly handle `rgb()`, `rgba()` and named colors cases. Color strings that start with hashes (`#`) are only a part of the deal.

As you have `iText7` as a dependency and `iText7` has a `pdfHTML` add-on which means the logic for parsing `CSS` colors obviously must be somewhere in `iText7` and, more importantly, it must handle various range of CSS color cases. The question is only about finding the right place. Fortunately, this API is public and easy to use.

The method you are interested in is `WebColors.getRGBAColor()` from package `com.itextpdf.kernel.colors` which accepts a `CSS` color string a returns a 4-element array with `R`, `G`, `B`, `A` values (last one stands for alpha, i.e. transparency).

You can use those values to create a color right away (code in Java):

```
float[] rgbaColor = WebColors.getRGBAColor("#ababab");
Color color = new DeviceRgb(rgbaColor[0], rgbaColor[1], rgbaColor[2]);
```

In Scala it must be something like

```
val rgbaColor = WebColors.getRGBAColor("#ababab");
val color = new DeviceRgb(rgbaColor(0), rgbaColor(1), rgbaColor(2));
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Of course you came up with the shortest solution, so this is my accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

I came up with this fun answer (untested); I guess the biggest help for you will be the use of `sliding(2,2)` instead of the `foldLeft`.

```
def stringToInts(colorString: String): Option[(Int, Int, Int)] = {
  val trimmedString: String => String = _.trim.replaceAll("#", "")

  val validString: String => Option[String] = s => s.length match {
    case 3 => Some(s.flatMap(c => s"$c$c"))
    case 6 => Some(s)
    case _ => None
  }

  val hex2rgb: String => List[Option[Int]] = _.sliding(2, 2).toList
    .map(hex => Try(Integer.parseInt(hex, 16)).toOption)

  val listOpt2OptTriple: List[Option[Int]] => Option[(Int, Int, Int)] = {
    case Some(r) :: Some(g) :: Some(b) :: Nil => Some(r, g, b)
    case _ => None
  }

  for {
    valid <- validString(trimmedString(colorString))
    rgb = hex2rgb(valid)
    answer <- listOpt2OptTriple(rgb)
  } yield answer
}
```

Comment: Untested, but works as expected :-)  Thank you. Sliding is awesome! What a beautiful programming language.

Comment: Apart from that many other parts of your solution look prettier than mine.

Comment: May I ask why you prefer `List` over `Seq`?

Comment: I also noticed something about your tests - you can use `assert (actual === Some(expected))` instead of your multiple assertions (if you like)

Comment: `Seq` is a trait; `List` is a concrete implementation of it. See SO question 10866639. In my `listOpt2OptTriple`, the match case using `::` and `Nil` is matching only a `List`. If you change the input type to a `Seq`, and the output of `hex2rgb` to a `Vector` (another type of `Seq`) (adding `.toVector` at the end), this will compile but always produce `None` - `Vector` is a `Seq` but cannot match `... :: Nil`. This kind of bug is rare but can be avoided by using the concrete `List` type unless you need to use more generic sequence types. HTH

Comment: If using `Seq`, you could match with `case Seq(Some(r), Some(g), Some(b)) =>`. This matches `List`, `Vector` and other `Seq`s.

Comment: I did not know that. I always used `Seq` because it seemed to be best suited for interface definitions (and of course is shorter than `List` or `Vector`). If I understand you correctly, I must avoid `::` and `Nil` to ensure good code maintainability. Because in most cases one is not required to distinguish between `List`, `Seq` and `Vector` when doing pattern matching. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: nitpick: `.sliding(2, 2)` is a bit strange since it's the same as `.grouped(2)`

Comment: All good comments. I don't know why I didn't think of `grouped(2)`!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible implementation of your function

```
def stringToInts(css: String): Option[(Int, Int, Int)] = {
  def cssColour(s: String): Int = {
    val v = Integer.parseInt(s, 16)

    if (s.length == 1) v*16 + v else v
  }

  val s = css.trim.replaceAll("#", "")
  val l = s.length/3

  if (l > 2 || l*3 != s.length) {
    None
  } else {
    Try{
      val res = s.grouped(l).map(cssColour).toSeq

      (res(0), res(1), res(2))
    }.toOption
  }
}
```

The implementation would be cleaner if it returned `Option[List[Int]]` or even `Try[List[Int]]` to preserve the error in the case of failure.

Comment: Refreshingly concise! I did not hope for such a short solution. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for conciseness, perhaps this solution will do the job (at the expense of efficiency—more on that later):

```
import scala.util.Try

def parseLongForm(rgb: String): Try[(Int, Int, Int)] =
  Try {
    rgb.replace("#", "").
      grouped(2).toStream.filter(_.length == 2).
      map(Integer.parseInt(_, 16)) match { case Stream(r, g, b) => (r, g, b) }
  }

def parseShortForm(rgb: String): Try[(Int, Int, Int)] =
  parseLongForm(rgb.flatMap(List.fill(2)(_)))

def parse(rgb: String): Option[(Int, Int, Int)] =
  parseLongForm(rgb).orElse(parseShortForm(rgb)).toOption
```

In terms of conciseness is that every function here is effectively a one-liner (if that's something you're looking for right now).

The core is the function `parseLongForm`, which attempts to parse the long 6-character long form by:

- removing the `#` character
- grouping the characters in pairs
- filtering out lone items (in case we have an odd number of characters)
- parsing each pair
- matching with the expected result to extract individual items

`parseLongForm` represents the possibility of failure with `Try`, which allows us to fail gracefully whenever `parseInt` or the pattern matching fails.

`parse` invokes `parseLongForm` and, if the result is a failure (`orElse`), invokes `parseShortForm`, which just tries the same approach after doubling each character.

It successfully passes the tests that you provided (kudos, that makes addressing the question **much** easier).

The main issue with this approach is that you would still try to parse the long form even if it can be clear from the beginning that it would not work. So, this is not recommended code if this could be a performance bottleneck for your use case. Another issue is that, although that's more or less hidden, we're using exceptions for flow control (which also hurts performance).

The nice things are conciseness and, I'd argue, readability (as I'd say that the code maps in a fairly straightforward fashion to the problem—but readability, of course, is by definition in the eye of the beholder).

You can find this solution [on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/AH4eVOyaTSmMwgZP9g8eDQ).

Comment: Thank you. I like your solution a lot, because it is the most concise without having to use a library (apart from `scala.util` ;-) ). Performance is not that relevant. In 99% of that project, concise and legible code are most important.